# Set empty error to TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a `TextInputLayout` which I want to set empty error to it **(I just want to make hint color and line color to be red)** but when I set empty error nothing happens and my `TextInputLayout` don't accept it as an error and nothing changed.
any help?

[image: and I don't want the error box to appear because I have many input text in vertical linearlayout]

and I don't want the error box to be appear because I have many input text in vertical linearlayout

Comment: Without your code it's hopeless

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the code for the `setError()` it has the following code

```
if (!mErrorEnabled) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(error)) {
                // If error isn't enabled, and the error is empty, just return
                return;
            }
```

you can use this workaround to make the line color red

```
   textInputPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
   textInputPassword.setError(" "); //white space
```

for the floating hint color programmaticly you can use this code

```
private void setUpperHintColor(int color) {
    try {
        Field field = textInputLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        int[][] states = new int[][]{
                new int[]{}
        };
        int[] colors = new int[]{
                color
        };
        ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        field.set(textInputLayout, myList);

        Method method = textInputLayout.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("updateLabelState", boolean.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(textInputLayout, true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, tamtom but this way error box appear and because I have many inputtext in linearLayout all my layout design changes

Comment: try this setError(null);